# Datastage 11.5 warning with character conversion (teradata connector)

Tags: utf-8, teradata, connector, datastage

i've a problem with a teradata connector. When i read from a table with the teradata connector it gives me this error :

"Conversion from the UTF-8 character set to ISO-8859-1 may affect performance"

Is there a way in order to eliminate this warning?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Codepage conversions will affect performance - but depending on source and target codepages these conversion may be necessary.
So check the codepage of you target and make sure you do not use a third codepage withing your DataStage job. The codepage of a job cen be found in the job properties.

Comment: I've checked but the codepage of the datastage job, it's not a third codepage. I've tried to switch between  the two present in the error but it continues to give me the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Message Handler Manager to handle this warning, or if your server has National Language Support installed, change the NLS of the project in the Administrator Client.

The NLS could be changed to a particular job

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me when I left a varchar set in unicode, in the tab "columns". it was fixed when set in nothing